# Shedlock for locking Quartz scheduler

Tags: quartz-scheduler, shedlock

I am looking for a locking solution for my scheduled tasks. I cannot use the in-built Quartz mechanism as I am not using JDBC. I came across Shedlock, but it seems to be tightly integrated with Spring Scheduler. I also came across https://www.baeldung.com/shedlock-spring, which suggests that it is an alternative to Quartz. Is my understanding correct that it is not a good option to use with Quartz scheduler?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory it should be possible to use Quartz with ShedLock using [this approach](https://github.com/lukas-krecan/ShedLock#running-without-spring).

But I am not sure that it's a good idea. It may be better to use custom jobstore Quartz class as [described here](https://dzone.com/articles/using-quartz-for-scheduling-with-mongodb).